# Communicate with subprocess by sending int data

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using `subprocess.Popen` to launch a new program which expects int data from stdin.

```
proc = Popen('command', shell=False,stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
proc.communicate(1)
```

Got error as

```
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

Can we have any other way out by which I can launch a new program and pass int data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `Popen.communicate()` must be a `bytes` or a `str` object. This should work in both Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
proc.communicate(b'1')
```

or using a variable:

```
proc.communicate(str(myint).encode())
```

For the ​sake of completeness, to send an actual integer instead of it's ASCIIfication, you could do:

```
proc.communicate(bytes(bytearray([myint])))
```

Comment: on *"send an actual integer"*: ascii representation is not less "actual" than e.g., [`myint.to_bytes((myint.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')` serialization for unsigned values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28524760/4279).  Human-readable representation should be preferable for exchanging data between processes unless you have a reason not to do it (e.g., due to performance, legacy apps). Note: your code `bytes(bytearray([myint]))` works only for `myint` in `range(0, 256)`, you could use `struct.pack('B', myint)` to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

As it says [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> The optional *input* argument should be a string to be sent to the child
>   process

so you will have to send `'1'` and then convert it in your program